# Ask more questions, and give more answers!

Tags: discussion

I recently ran across some [site stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion) and noticed we do an amazing job at **answering 99% of the questions** asked on tridion.stackexchange. I think this means we have a very active community and asking a question is worth the effort. From my experience on this site I know that the quality of the questions & answers, and the speed of answering is also pretty amazing.

[image: 99 percent answered]

I think **the next step** is to ask more questions and give more answers.

**Ask more questions**, even if you have a simple question, if you answered your own question through your research or if you think no one knows the answer on your questions. I have been surprised quite a few times with the in depth details on ECL, ADF and SmartTarget answers lately while these topics are a bit of a niche in Tridion (for sure it helps that some R&D folks are active on the site).

Just put more of your questions on the site, and it will make a healthier site which will draw more users, and make a busier retreat in Portugal ;) I am sure that we have more than 3.8 questions per day.

[image: 3.8 questions per day]

**Give more answers**, even if you don't know the fully detailed scientifically proven tested answer in proper English. Don't think that your answer will have to compete with other answers. The most valuable questions on tridion.stackexchange are those which have multiple answers, answering in various level of detail, with different opinions, different practices. Consider to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), a great way to share your knowledge. Currently we are doing 1.9 answers per question.

[image: 1.9 answers per question]

At **[480 visits a day](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)** have almost accomplished the [goal of 500 visits a day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5UWE.png). I am sure that with more questions an answers we will also draw more traffic which helps founding a healthy site.

[image: 480 visits per day]

Comment: Great point and reminder, @Jan. The pictures make it a good call-to-action. I'm seeing how 99% means the questions are too easy or too few (for now). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Right on the money Jan, simply put we need to attract more ppl that register on the site and start using it, that will automatically increase all of these.

But for those that are already here, we indeed can focus on coming back more than once per day to check out the new stuff and make sure that we add an answer of ourselves to any question where we can give a sensible answer. I think the aim here should be:

1. if you see and answer that is wrong and you can fix that with a simple edit, just edit the answer (you won't get points for it, but I think its better for the community to fix the answer rather than to downvote it and provide your own, although that is an option)
2. if you see an answer and you can provide a different view (or perhaps a better answer) add your own (if its better it should get more votes)
3. most important, don't add duplicate answers with just different wording or better grammar

We want the answer ratio to rise higher than 1.9, but we want that to be honest and valid too. We have to accept that some of the Tridion questions simply have only one answer, that's is just a fact of life (or the product).

Last remark on #2, we need to vote more on the site. There are a lot of old questions like [this one](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/broker-and-linking-log-not-generating-sdl-tridion-2009-sp-1/2924) that only have a single vote on the given answers, while there currently are 715 registered users on this site and 133 of them marked as avid.

ps. this answer is not directed at you personally, I'm glad you opened this discussion, and hope more will come to respond with their opinion.

Comment: Thanks. It is not only by the statistics, we cannot change the quality of the site by pushing up the stats. But still, more activity, more questions, answers, comments and votes will naturally make a more active community and a better site.