# Why can't we move out from Beta to official release

Tags: discussion

All the stats looks good:

[image]

Is there some specific schedule when we are supposed to evaluate the site and move from Beta to the Official release. What is the criteria apart from what we can see from the stats image above for the official release?

Comment: I agree that the stats look good... but does it really matter if we're still in Beta? Stats looking good means that - hopefully - stackexchange won't drop us anymore. Other than that, I don't really care if we're in Beta or not.

Comment: I completely agree with you Nuno the only thing I was curious to know as I might be unaware of policies of stackexchange for Beta sites and dropping of beta site after some duration

Comment: I don't think there's an automatic "get this and you're out of beta" criteria. I'm pretty sure it's evaluated by real people. The fact that we, as such as small community compared to other SE sites, have even managed to get into the beta and stay there is amazing enough :D

Comment: Stack Exchange has some sites that are +1000 days in Beta. I think they have killed off a few truly dead Beta sites which this site is far from being.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification everyone...I think the outcome is that, we should only concentrate on Learning from the community, sharing our learning, knowledge & experiences and helping the community instead of thinking if the site is in Beta or an official release.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is in many ways likely the same as to the question [Ask more questions, and give more answers!](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/ask-more-questions-and-give-more-answers) asked by Jan H a couple weeks ago.

In the end SE wants to make sure when a community does graduate it will continue to be an active, vibrant and thriving community.

What does this mean for us? To some extent it means we need more questions, more answers and more users.

With that said, from some of the back and forth we had with some of the SE Community Managers back when we were in private beta (and the early days of the public beta), I got the impression they were very aware the Tridion Stack Exchange is going to be relatively small community and they seemed fine with that as long as the community we built was a vibrant one.